# save xml file using streamwriter

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to find a way to save data back to an xml file with an encoding "iso-8859-7".

firstly am loading the xml using

```
    public XmlDocument LoadDocument(String x)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(xml, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7"));
        document.Load(stream);
        return (document);
    }
```

to load attributes inside form controls and then when the save button is clicked

```
    private void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNodeList attributes = commonMethods.LoadDocument(xml).DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + classname + "']/Property[@Id='" + id + "']/attribute::*");
        for (int x = 0; x < attributes.Count; )
        {
            foreach (Control ctr in table1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctr is TextBox)
                {
                    if (ctr.Text == attributes[x].Value.ToString()) { x++; }
                    else
                    {
                        attributes[x].Value = ctr.Text; commonMethods.SaveDocument(xml);
                        x++;
                    }
                }
                else if (ctr is ComboBox)
                {
                    if (((ComboBox)ctr).Text == attributes[x].Value) { x++; }
                    else
                    {
                        attributes[x].Value = ((ComboBox)ctr).Text; commonMethods.SaveDocument(xml);
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it saves the changes back to the xml file. I used to save it without using xmlwriter like `xmldoc.Save("sample.xml)` but because of some characters inside the file I had to use a different approach like.

```
    public XmlDocument SaveDocument(String x)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(x,false,Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7"));
        document.Save(xml);
        return (document);
    }
```

The problem is when I compile it says **"xml is used by another process"** and it fails.

System.IO.IOException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this exception because the file is still opened by the StreamReader that is pending for finalization (garbage collection).
You should always dispose your streams (and reader / writers) to release the file handle as soon as possible.

```
public XmlDocument LoadDocument(String path)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")))
    {
        document.Load(stream);

    }
    return (document);
}


public XmlDocument SaveDocument(XmlDocument document, String path)
{
    using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(path,false,Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")))
    {
        document.Save(stream);
    }
    return (document);
}


private void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = commonMethods.LoadDocument(xml);
    XmlNodeList attributes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + classname + "']/Property[@Id='" + id + "']/attribute::*");
    for (int x = 0; x < attributes.Count; )
    {
        foreach (Control ctr in table1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr is TextBox)
            {
                if (ctr.Text == attributes[x].Value.ToString()) { x++; }
                else
                {
                    attributes[x].Value = ctr.Text; commonMethods.SaveDocument(doc, xml);
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else if (ctr is ComboBox)
            {
                if (((ComboBox)ctr).Text == attributes[x].Value) { x++; }
                else
                {
                    attributes[x].Value = ((ComboBox)ctr).Text; commonMethods.SaveDocument(doc, xml);
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it gives me the error: "The document does not have a root element" over the line document.Save(stream); I opened the file and it was empty

Comment: Maybe because your document doesn't have a root element ;) You have to add elements to your document before saving it. I edited my answer...

Comment: document has content. full of content actually.

Comment: `var doc = new Document(); doc.Save(...)` No, there is no content

Comment: basically I want to load and write the xml file with different encoding using xmldocument. is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't **dispose** the `StreamReader` object after loading the document

add the `using` statement:

```
public XmlDocument LoadDocument(String x)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(xml, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")))
      {
        document.Load(stream);

      }
      return (document);
    }
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx